# an error after log in: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection which must be closed first?"

Tags: vb.net

I retrieve it in my mainform:

```
Try
        rs.Connection = con
        cmd = "select * from cdcol.currency_rate"
        rs.CommandText = cmd
        res = rs.ExecuteReader

        While res.Read
            Dim currency = res.GetString("currency")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(currency)
        End While
        res.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

and this in my tabcontrol

```
Try
            rs.Connection = con
            cmd = "select * from cdcol.currency_rate where currency='" & ComboBox2.Text & "'"
            rs.CommandText = cmd
            res = rs.ExecuteReader
        While res.Read
            If sell.Checked = True Then
                buy.Text = res.GetDouble("buy_rate")
                coderate.Text = res.GetString("code")
            End If
            If buy.Checked = True Then
                sell.Text = res.GetDouble("sell_rate")
                coderate.Text = ("PHP")
            End If
        End While
        res.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

**when i log in there was an error,**
**what's wrong with my codes ?**
**please help me ..**

Answer (score 0):

A few things could be going on, hard to tell without all the code but I'll give you some ideas.  I'm assuming this is a WinForms app (also assuming this is SQL Server)?

If you've verified that all your DataReader's are being closed properly then it is possible that you have two DataReaders actually trying to read at the same time if they're using a shared connection in your program (you say you're using a tab control and executing a query, if you have one reader running somewhere and then you click on a tab you could run into that scenario).  If that is your desired behavior you can allow multiple recordsets by adding the multiple active result sets flag to your connection string:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like this:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" & _
"Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

The MSDN article gives you much more info about it.  In your scenario this will probably work.  MSDN offers this though (which is your other option, use a connection per method you need it and dispose of it when you're done):

> "MARS is not designed to remove all requirements for multiple
>   connections in an application. If an application needs true parallel
>   execution of commands against a server, multiple connections should be
>   used."